# How to get syslog file in Redhat

Tags: redhat

I have installed collectd on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2 server.

I have also installed it on ubuntu 14.04 server.

In ubuntu when I run the service collectd and face any error , I can easily go to `/var/log/syslog` to get the error message and reason.

But when I get error message on my Red Hat server like this :

[image]

and I go to `/var/log` I did not get the file syslog.

As I don't have much/no experience with Red Hat , can some body tell me where to find syslog file in Red Hat server in order to trouble shoot my errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share output of "ls -alt /var/log | head -10" command?

Comment: Try to look at ```/var/log/messages```

Comment: @stresscool : I have gone through `/var/log/messages` but I did not find there any information regarding my service.

Comment: @AliOkanYüksel
Here is the output of the command you provided.
total 748
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Aug 24 04:37 .
-rw-------  1 root root 133221 Aug 24 04:37 messages
-rw-------  1 root root  10897 Aug 24 04:37 secure
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root   4096 Aug 24 04:37 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 146292 Aug 24 04:35 lastlog
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp  28800 Aug 24 04:35 wtmp
-rw-------  1 root utmp   3072 Aug 24 04:32 btmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 260909 Aug 24 04:32 cloud-init.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   9094 Aug 24 04:32 cloud-init-output.log

Answer (score 7):

RH uses journald for logging and has moved away from syslog and flat files per se.  The best thing to do is to look at the logs for your specific service.  Such as:

```
sudo journalctl -u <service/yourservice.service>
```

You can also lots of output options such as output in JSON or only output for the past hour

```
sudo journalctl -u <service> --since "1 hour ago"
```

Look here for an extensive overview of what you can do with journald commands: [Journald system logs tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs)

Answer (score 3):

**systemclt status yourservice.service**

complete syslog will be on **/var/log**

if you not configure on rsyslog.conf file. all your apps will be log on messages file

**less /var/log/messages**

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 7.x uses journald for logging, your installation might not have syslog redirection enabled. To view system log use `journalctl`.

Answer (score 0):

log files are present under /var/log but if you want to see perticular process log then u can also give grep command along with that another way is

> systemctl status processname